# What cause Eigen::VectorXd destruct error?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a class call `KalmanFilter`

```
class KalmanFilter {
public:
  bool Init(const Eigen::VectorXd &initial_belief_states,
            const Eigen::MatrixXd &initial_uncertainty);
  
  Eigen::VectorXd GetStates() const;
private:
  Eigen::VectorXd global_states_;
  Eigen::MatrixXd global_uncertainty_;
};

Eigen::VectorXd KalmanFilter::GetStates() const { return global_states_; }
```

Then call in another class

```cpp
KalmanFilter kalman_filter_;
Eigen::VectorXd state = kalman_filter_.GetStates();
```

I confirmed that the program crashes when the state is released, and no coredump file is generated.
I confirm that the state is assigned and printed out

```
GetStates: 00000587071
4.14164e+06
00000000000
00000000000
00000000000
00000000000
```

I know my question may not be very specific, but what I want to know is **what causes the eigen release to fail**, and I don't know where the error is?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]! Even if the crash happens during an Eigen operation, there may be an error elsewhere which causes this.

Comment: The only thing the vector destructor does is deallocate memory. The only way this can go wrong is if you corrupted the stack or the heap. Nothing in the code you've shown could cause that. So the issue is with the surrounding code. Either show more of it or try running a memory sanitizer on your own